# Can someone suggest the optimised way to do the below?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    
    const Parent = (props) => {
      let [id, setId] = useState(1);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setId(++id % 4);
            }}
          >
            Increment
          </button>
          {id === 1 && <h2>Image 1</h2>}
          {id === 2 && <h2>Image 2</h2>}
          {id === 3 && <h2>Image 3</h2>}
          {id === 0 && <h2>Image 4</h2>}
          {id}
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setId(Math.abs(--id) % 4);
            }}
          >
            Decrement
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

- my decrement is not working fine can someone check this
  I am trying to select the images based on button click of user increment is working fine but decrement is not working here Can someone help me here *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the `id` is set to `1` and when you click `decrement` then it will become `0`, so far so good.

But as soon as you hit `decrement` again then it will be `-1` but you have used `Math.abs` so it will make it to `1` and this goes on and on

You can just change the login a bit as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-microservice-rzyw14?file=/src/App.js)

```
onClick={() => {
  const newId = --id;
  setId(newId < 0 ? 3 : newId);
}}
```

You can also use below logic as:

```
setId((--id + 4) % 4);
```